# How to convert a binary number to a two-digit decimal number in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I need to convert a binary number to a two-digit decimal number. For example:

```
01111 becomes 15
00011 becomes 03
```

I'm not simply trying to display the digits. I need to put each digit into an int variable. Say I have two int variables, leftnum and rightnum.

Then in the first example, leftnum = 1 and rightnum = 5.
In the second example, leftnum = 0 and rightnum = 3.

There are two restrictions which make this a little difficult. mod and / can only be used with powers of 2.

Comment: Is this homework? It's okay to ask questions about homework assignments, but please say so if you do.

Comment: How your bits are stored? In a char array? Or you have the int?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "binary number"? Do you mean that you are reading '1' and '0' characters from stdandard input? Or do you mean that you have an array of ints, each of which is '1' or '0'? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter that the number is binary. You can consider the number to be an int. The problem is getting the right values into the two variables.

Comment: This isn't a homework question, but it is related to a project that I'm doing.

Comment: What distinguishes this question from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275672/how-to-split-up-a-two-digit-number-in-c

Comment: @z-buffer ofcourse it matters if the number is binary or a char array of '1' and '0'. In the former case you just have to convert the int to a decimal representation - which there already is a simple standard function for(sprintf() ). In the latter case you'll have to parse the 1's and 0's which there isn't a standard function for

Comment: The difference between this question and the previous question is that this has one more constraint added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
do {
    i ++;
} while (i * 10 <= originalInt);

int leftInt = i - 1; // e.g. for "originalInt = 40" -> "i = 5", so we must decrement 1
int rightInt = originalInt - leftInt * 10;
```

---

or more compact and using less variables:

```
int leftInt = 0;
do {leftInt ++;} while (leftInt * 10 <= originalInt);
int rightInt = originalInt - (-- leftInt) * 10;
```

Comment: @z-buffer it's quite tricky because I've tried to make it more compact. See updated answer. And one correction: **<=** instead of just **<**

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i = 23;
  int left, right;

  right = i;
  left = 0;
  while(right > 9) {
    right -= 10;
    left += 1;
  }
  printf("%d %d\n", left, right);
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, left, right;
  for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    left = ((i+1)*51) / 512;
    right = i - (left*10);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i, left, right);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general procedure in English:

1. Convert the number to decimal i.e. the int type of C (if bitstring is represented by string) else skip this step.
2. Use sprintf to obtain the decimal representation of int.
3. You can pick each character from the string and store the corresponding number accordingly to the require int.