# How do you implement the remainder method % for integers in java? How fast is it?

Tags: java, int

Naive implementation: if you want to find `p % q`, subtract `q` from `p` until you get a `number < q`. This takes `p/q` subtractions, and `p/q` comparisons.

How does Java actually do this, and how fast is it?

Comment: Java does it by asking the CPU to do it, and it is fast. How fast? Well, relative to what???

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because the question is asked in the context of Java. There is more going on when JVM gets involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Java compiler sees `%` operator, it generates one of the typed `rem` [bytecode instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings), e.g. `irem`, `lrem`, `frem`, `drem`, etc. The actual instruction depends on the type. For two `int`s the instruction is `irem`.

These instructions get interpreted by JVM, producing CPU actions for obtaining the remainder.

Most CPUs these days (at least, the ones capable of running Java) have built-in instructions that take a divisor and a dividend, and produce a quotient and remainder pair. That is why `%` operator is as fast as the division operator `/`.

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5454574/335858) for information on how the instruction itself may be implemented in the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Java actually do this

Java uses the underlying CPU instruction.

> how fast is it?

Most CPUs support integer division which also produces a remainder. The original 8086 did this. This is not cheap but it is O(1) in terms of time in modern CPUs.

Note: -5 % 3 = -2 i.e. -5 = -1 * 3 + -2