# How to calculate division remainder in SPARC Assembly?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, division, integer-division, sparc

Here is the pseudo code which computes division of two positive integers.
HR register saves remainder, and LR saves dividend. (and eventually saves root)

However I think this algorithm has some problem.
Because this algorithm sometimes don't recover subtraction.(Division is a continuation of subtraction.)

For example `6 / 3 (0110 / 011)`
This algorithm subtract -3 one more time. (This situation never occur when we calculate this division by hand)
So I think this algorithm has some problem.
Don't you agree with me?
How to calculate division remainder in Assembly?

```
for i = 1 to num_of_bits do
(HR LR) << 1
if (HR >= 0) then
   HR = HR - DIVISOR
else
   HR = HR + DIVISOR
endif
if (HR > 0) then LR(lsb) = 1 endif
endfor
```

Comment: This is assembly?!  For what chip?

Comment: in SPARC. I must have written what architecture is..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189631/how-can-i-take-mod-of-a-number-in-assembly-in-motorola-m6800/5189800#5189800. As originally asked, the question was about the 6800, but the answer is about eqally applicable to any processor without a divide instruction.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Wow, That's so awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't speak SPARC asm, but I do speak C. Here's a sample implementation of the algorithm for 16/8=8,8 division:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned int uint;

int u8div(uint8* dividendh, uint8* dividendl, uint8 divisor)
{
  int i;

  if (*dividendh >= divisor)
    return 0; // overflow

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (*dividendh >= 0x80)
    {
      *dividendh = (*dividendh << 1) | (*dividendl >> (8 - 1));
      *dividendl <<= 1;

      *dividendh -= divisor;
      *dividendl |= 1;
    }
    else
    {
      *dividendh = (*dividendh << 1) | (*dividendl >> (8 - 1));
      *dividendl <<= 1;

      if (*dividendh >= divisor)
      {
        *dividendh -= divisor;
        *dividendl |= 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

int u8div2(uint8* dividendh, uint8* dividendl, uint8 divisor)
{
  uint dividend = (*dividendh << 8) | *dividendl;

  if (*dividendh >= divisor)
    return 0; // overflow

  *dividendl = dividend / divisor;
  *dividendh = dividend % divisor;

  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  uint dividendh, dividendl, divisor;

  for (dividendh = 0; dividendh <= 0xFF; dividendh++)
    for (dividendl = 0; dividendl <= 0xFF; dividendl++)
      for (divisor = 0; divisor <= 0xFF; divisor++)
      {
        uint8 divh = dividendh, divl = dividendl, divr = divisor;
        uint8 divh2 = dividendh, divl2 = dividendl;

        printf("0x%04X/0x%02X=", (divh << 8) | divl, divr);

        if (u8div(&divh, &divl, divr))
          printf("0x%02X.0x%02X", divl, divh);
        else
          printf("ovf");

        printf(" ");

        if (u8div2(&divh2, &divl2, divr))
          printf("0x%02X.0x%02X", divl2, divh2);
        else
          printf("ovf");

        if ((divl != divl2) || (divh != divh2))
          printf(" err"); // "err" will be printed if u8div() computes incorrect result

        printf("\n");
      }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that `if (*dividendh >= 0x80)
    {
      *dividendh = (*dividendh << 1) | (*dividendl >> (8 - 1));
      *dividendl <<= 1;

      *dividendh -= divisor;
      *dividendl |= 1;
    }` is not necessary

Comment: @manutd: if you remove that part, the code won't always work correctly. I'm going to update the answer with more code to demonstrate it.

Comment: I agree with you in case of that dividendh has some initial value (!= 0) But If dividendh has initial value as 0, The result of two function is same.

Comment: Could you tell me Why did you put non-zero value in dividendh? Isn't it a reminder? If it is reminder, Wouldn't it be better to set the initial value of dividendh to zero?

Comment: @manutd: many CPUs's division instructions divide 2N bits by N bits (and return N bits of quotient and N bits of remainder) basically doing the opposite of multiplication where you multiply N bits by N bits and get 2N bits. That's what I did. The calculations are done in-place (the remainder appears in dividendh and quotient in dividendl), which is also very typical of those divide instructions and division subroutines.

Comment: Thanks. However, in your code, you put the non-zero initial value to dividendh(`for (dividendh = 0; dividendh <= 0xFF; dividendh++)`). the initial setting value of remainder is non-zero. I wonder why you did?

Comment: @manutd: I explained it: *dividendh contains 8 most significant bits of the dividend before calling u8div(), but after the call it contains the remainder.

Answer (score 3):

Several implementation of the division algorithm (that also computes the remainder) can be found in appendix E of the [SPARC architecture manual](http://www.sparc.com/standards/V8.pdf).

Newer version of the SPARC architecture include the division operators UDIV and SDIV.

A furhter implemenation can be found [here](http://cristi.indefero.net/p/uClibc-cristi/source/tree/0_9_19/libc/sysdeps/linux/sparc/urem.S).