# Software implementation of integer division in LLVM backend

Tags: code-generation, llvm

I'm trying to implement a codegen (I seek for assembler listing only, not a binary code) for custom architecture which doesn't have hardware implementation of integer division. I use clang frontend and get symbols like  __divsi3 in my assembler listing. I see an [implementation of __divsi3 in compiler_rt library of LLVM](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/divsi3.c). How could I use this?

Comment: You can adapt the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7709021/968261).

Comment: I don't ask for algorithm of division, but for a way of using standard library function.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate it or provide an example of what you want?

Comment: I suppose you should compile libcompile_rt into bitcode and then substitute calls like __divsi3 with their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll use your new compiler to compile the appropriate functions in compiler-rt that your processor is missing. Then include the compiler-rt library at link time so the unresolved symbol can be resolved.

__divsi3 is just a simple C function that uses simpler operations to perform the division that your architecture doesn't support.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thank you. The only gotcha I have, is that I have no control on linkage, my codegen just generates asm. And I'm not sure that the current setting allows for multi-file linkage. I have to elaborate on asm-to-bin tool documentation — whether it can link multiple asm files.

Comment: No problem. Just compile the compiler-rt files to bitcode, use llvm-link to link the rt objects with your application code bitcode, and then run the result through your code generator.

Comment: I found necessary linker option. But I have another problem now: how to told LLVM to add an external declaration for the function which implements integer division…