# multiplying two 32-Bit Numbers and printing the 64 bit result as decimal NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have a problem using NASM assembly.

I can't figure out how to multiply 2 numbers and print them to the screen.

The problem is that we are only allowed to use a function which only prints 32-bit length number; not 64-bit length numbers.

So my problem is probably with the math, I think I need to use Horner's method to get the the decimal number; like I indicate below.

If I have

```
AF / A = 11 remaining 5 
11 / A = 1 remaining 7
1 / A = 0 remaining 1
```

-> 175 which is the right result

but when I split it up in two registers here each 4 byte just as an example

```
A | F    A / A = 1 remaining 0 and F / A = 1 remaining 5
         1 / A = 0 remaining 1
```

->150 which is wrong

Here is my assembly code

```
mov eax, [Zahl1]
mul dword [Zahl2]
mov [High], edx


;---- low-----
mov ebx, 10
loopbegin:
;dividing by 10
xor edx, edx
div ebx

;counting
inc dword [counter]

;saving the number 
push edx
cmp eax, 0
jne loopbegin

mov ebx, 10
; --- high ----
mov eax, [High]
highloop:
xor edx, edx
div ebx

inc dword [counter]

push edx
cmp eax, 0
jne highloop
```

`<note>` here follows the loop that prints the numbers from the stack

Comment: Is this all of your assembly code?  Can you please edit to include everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just convert+print the two halves separately, because the bits of the high half represent `4294967296 * hi` in the whole 64-bit number.

`4294967296` is not a power of 10, so bits in the high half affect the low decimal digits.  If you were printing in a power-of-2 base, like hex or octal, your method would work because division by the radix would just be a shift: i.e. the low hex digit is determined by just the low 4 bits.  But the low decimal digit depends on all 64 binary bits.

---

Instead, you need to do 64-bit division by 10.  This takes multiple `div` instructions because `div r32` (64b / 32b => 32b) faults if the quotient overflows 32 bits.  **See [Assembler 64b division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965098/assembler-64b-division) for working code for extended-precision division**.  (But don't use `xchg` with memory; use some extra registers instead).

(`div` is slow and `mul` is very fast on modern CPUs; it might be worth doing extended-precision multiply to get the high half of a 64b * 64b => 128b multiply for [a fixed-point multiplicative inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi) to divide by 10 faster.)

---

Also, you don't need to `push` the digits, and you don't need a counter in memory.  Just use an extra register for a pointer that starts at the end of a buffer.  See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) for how to write the surrounding code, just replace the 32-bit division in the inner loop with extended-precision using two `div` instructions.