# How to find remainder without using div in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm wondering how one goes about finding the remainder of an integer if one can't use the div operand. For instance:

```
mov eax, 400    ; 400 / 4 
shr eax, 2      ; Remainder : 0


mov eax, 397    ; 397 / 4
shr eax, 2      ; Remainder : 1


mov eax, 394    ; 394 / 4
shr eax, 2      ; Remainder : 2
```

Shifting truncates the remainder.

So without using `div` (which stores the remainder in `edx`) what can one do to figure out what the remainder was?

Comment: Division by a power of two is simple bit manipulation (and thus also for the remainder), but for a general divisor (like 17) it's not so easy.

Comment: After the shr eax,2 save that result; then mult it by 4 and sub that from the original num. There's your remainder.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was on the right track. Just didn't quite get there. :) Much appreciated. @PeteWilson if you'd like to put your reply in an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll just put in an answer. Kerrek SB thanks for explaining, could you elaborate on the bit manipulation part?

Comment: For the general case (not just power of two) see [my answer to a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189631/how-can-i-take-mod-of-a-number-in-assembly-in-motorola-m6800/5189800#5189800).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks, that was a good read. Upvoted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just wanting the remainder when dividing by a power-of-two like in your example, then the remainder is really just the lower order bits of your input (those bits that you shifted out).  So, apply a bit-masking operator and you can immediately retrieve the remainder without any further arithmetic.

In microsoft x86 assembly language, I believe your first example would look like:

```
mov eax, 400    ; 400 / 4 
and eax, 3h     ; Masking with hex 3 (the lowest two bits) retrieves the remainder
```